# Mac calls URL of QR code token. Could this be malicious behavior?

Tags: macos, mac, security

I received an email that my Canarytoken QR code was triggered. This QR code is only stored locally on my Mac. I was not working on the Mac at the time.

It reminded me directly of this story: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33100130
The story was also the original reason I created the token in the first place. However, the token has been sitting on my disk for months now without any events.

The QR code was triggered twice within one minute with two different user agents:

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Safari/605.1.15

Client/28420 CFNetwork/1404.0.5 Darwin/22.3.0

The request came from my IP address. So it was definitely my Mac.

What can this be? I'm just guessing that some system process is causative and there is no malicious behavior here. If it's not malicious, I wonder what triggered the URL call and for what purpose.

Comment: Actually, this happened to me as well today and I would like to find out why. What is more interesting is the fact that the URL was exactly the same as one I accessed two months ago.